# Location of files on Unix whose file names and contents each match a regular expression

Tags: unix, find

I want to search for file names with a regular expression, and [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) it using regex. I tried this:

```
find .  -name co_on*eruo* | xargs grep '0LF2C Comdty(.*)20111022(.*)'
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Is "co_on*eruo*" a regex or a glob? Either way, I'm sure it should be quoted. I can't tell you how to fix it since you don't say what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
find .  -regex co_on*eruo* | xargs grep '0LF2C Comdty(.*)20111022(.*)'
```

Comment: You still need to quote `co_on*eruo*` so the shell doesn't expand it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you provide some explanation about why your code works?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, exactly *how* doesn't it work?

You need to quote the pattern (note: it's not a regex) to keep the shell from expanding it:

```
find .  -name 'co_on*eruo*' | xargs grep '0LF2C Comdty(.*)20111022(.*)'
```

**EDIT**

But if that's really supposed to be a regex (i.e., you want to match "co_o", then zero or more "n"s, then "eru", then zero or more "o"s), then as Tim says you need to use `-regex` rather than `-name`.  (That's probably a GNU-specific feature; if `find --version` doesn't say something like `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`, then your `find` might not support `-regex`.)

Comment: it can't find any file in the first part .

Comment: my find version:  find --version
GNU find version 4.2.27
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX

Comment: I changed to find .  -regex 'c*option*eruo*' , still no result.

Comment: That's not the same regular expression as the one in your question.  Without knowing what files you have and what they contain, we can't tell what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wan't the parantheses in the `grep` expression, or where they only there since you thought you needed them for the regexp functionality?

As it looks, you could probably do what you want with `grep` directly:

```
grep -R --include='co_on*eruo*' '0LF2C Comdty.*20111022.*'
```

---

Perhaps you want `-name` to span directory names as well - it doesn't. Give more info on the exact paths if you want a solution for that.